# Listing optimized binary function sizes in bytes

Tags: c, linux, optimization, embedded, objdump

I am optimizing my code for an MCU, I want to see the overview of sizes of all functions in my C program including all libraries, like say:

```
$ objdump some arguments that I do not know | pipe through something | clean the result some how
```

```
_main: 300 bytes
alloc: 200 bytes
do_something: 1111 bytes
etc...
```

Comment: Map files are used for this very purpose. Surely your linker can be told to generate one, so that you don't have to resort to all this icky Unix goo. Since you might also want to see where things end up in memory, if you have an actual MCU, then that means storing code in flash and usually running it from there as well. Memory consumption, where you might need wait states etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
nm -S -t d a.out | grep function_name | awk '{gsub ("0*", "", $2); print $2}'
```

Or print a list of sorted sizes for each symbol:

```sh
nm -S --size-sort -t d a.out | awk '{gsub ("0*", "", $2); print $4 " " $2}'
```

`nm` list symbols from object files. We are using `-S` to print the size of defined symbols in the second column and `-t d` to make output in decimal format.

Comment: I am getting `gsub third parameter is not a changeable object` on the second one

Comment: @exebook Thanks, it was a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: Thanks. Btw `--size-sort` does not work properly, so I removed it and added `sort -n` at the end. (Also reversing $2 and $4).

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ objdump a.out -t|grep "F .text"|cut -f 2-3
```

```
00000000000000b1              __slow_div
00000000000000d8              __array_compact_and_grow
00000000000000dc              __log
00000000000000de              __to_utf
00000000000000e9              __string_compact
00000000000000fe              __gc_release
000000000000001d              __gc_check
000000000000001f              array_compact
00000000000001e8              __string_split
000000000000002a              c_roots_clear
000000000000002f              f
000000000000002f              _start
000000000000002f              wpr
000000000000003d              array_get
```

Not perfect, sizes are in hex, but it's easy to write a script that will convert to decimals and sort arbitrarily.